# Error using win10toast: pywintypes.error: (-2147467259, 'Shell_NotifyIcon', 'Unspecified error')

Tags: python, python-3.x, notifications

I couldn't find anything anywhere about this error, I am trying to make a simple TCP chat with socket. I have made a function that makes a notification pop up on a users screen. But when I try to run it, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\James\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\TCP chat\toas.py", line 4, in 
> toaster.show_toast("Hello World!!!",
> File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win10toast_*init*_.py", line 127, in show_toast
> self.*show_toast(title, msg, icon_path, duration)
> File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win10toast_*init**.py", line 106, in _show_toast
> Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)
> pywintypes.error: (-2147467259, 'Shell_NotifyIcon', 'Unspecified error')

I don't know what it is, all I'm doing is a simple "show_toast":

```
mes = message[len(nickname)+9:]
msg = mes.split(": ")
print(f"{msg[0]}\n{msg[1]}")
t.show_toast(msg[0], msg[1])
```

Can anyone help?

***EDIT:***

My code was working fine before, it just suddenly stopped working. I didn't do anything or change any settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey buddy when you are calling `t.show_toast()` function you are not giving it the icon path which will be shown when notification comes so you can just add `icon_path=None`

So you can just try this `t.show_toast(msg[0], msg[1]), icon_path=None)`

Thanks I hope it helped,
Jai hind jai bharat