# win10toast error : pywintypes.error: (-2147467259, 'Shell_NotifyIcon', 'Unspecified error')

Tags: python, windows, winapi, notifications, updates

I am trying to return the current_time or current_time +1 in a func, where I am using the win10toast. My code was working fine before, it just suddenly stopped working. I didn't do anything or change any settings. When running the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

toast = ToastNotifier()
def At_Time():
    global Input_time, Ahead_time
    At_time = datetime.now()
    Ahead_time = (At_time + timedelta(minutes=1))

    if timedelta(seconds=At_time.second) < timedelta(seconds=30):
        L = 'Less Than 30 secs... Not changing Current_time'
        infoL = str('Current Time:  ' + At_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + '\n' + "Input Time:  " + At_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        toast.show_toast(title=L, msg=infoL, duration=7, threaded= True)
        Input_time = At_time.strftime("%H:%M")
        return Input_time
    else:
        M = 'More than 30 secs... Adding 1 Min to Current_time'
        infoM = str("Current Time:  " + At_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + '\n' + "Input Time:  " + Ahead_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        toast.show_toast(title=M, msg=infoM, duration=7, threaded= True)
        Input_time = Ahead_time.strftime("%H:%M")
        # meeting_row = Row
        return Input_time

At_Time()
```

When running this, I am now getting the following Error :

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner self.run()
     File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
     File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\win10toast\__init__.py", line 106, in 
   show_toast Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)
 pywintypes.error: (-2147467259, 'Shell_NotifyIcon', 'Unspecified error')`
```

Specifically speaking, This is the Error :

> ```
> pywintypes.error: (-2147467259, 'Shell_NotifyIcon', 'Unspecified error')
> ```

I could not find this issue reported anywhere except one https://stackoverflow.com/a/65224994/15136959, where the solution said to use

> icon_path= None

This is not going to work as it is already the default value of parameter. I assume the error is associated with the *Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)* , or an Win API Error. This bug/issue is nowhere else mentioned. Can I get reason for this Error, or a fix directly ?

Thanks for the help and your valuable time...

EDIT: This **Error got fixed** after a Restart. Also during the Restart, Windows got an

> "Updating Windows, Do Not Turn Off PC"

, even though I paused the Windows Updates. But still, someone got a permanent fix or even a reason why this occurred, So as to avoid any future issues by other users ??

Lastly, Can a Genius explain.. How can we show multiple notifications by win10toast at the same time, without the *Registered Class* Error ? ( Optional )

Comment: *"This is not going to work"* - Have you tried?

Comment: Yess, I tried first using **img_path=None** and then I also tried by specifying the icon.ico path, But none worked here. I think this something like "Memory Occupied Error", since it did occur once I lock windows and then sign in again, or after Hibernation.

Comment: Also, Forgot to mention that the Update did not Complete successfully, So windows rolled back. Can this be the reason for the issue ??

Comment: Thanks for your support, I too now cannot reproduce the problem after the Restart :(
But for Multiple Notifications, (As a Beginner) I found that apps like Mail and Chrome can show multiple notifications but win10toast cannot... Can this feature be likely added as a feature in the future.... or its Impossible ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem with this code, but a similar problem appears in [this](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/issues/18) thread, I think it is caused by the python script triggering win10toast at the same time. Then, you can refer to: Stopping all automatic updates Windows 10 to stop Win10 Update automatically.

Then, you can refer to: [Stopping all automatic updates Windows 10 to stop Win10 Update automatically.](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10) to stop Win10 Update automatically.

Finally, you cannot display multiple notifications at the same time. While one notification is active the second one won't be triggered. If needed you can reduce the duration of the first toast. Setting the duration of first toast as 3 seconds and this would work fine.

Regarding whether multiple notifications will be displayed at the same time in the future, Microsoft has not made it clear at present, and it does not seem to be added in the future.I think you can report the demand to Microsoft.

Comment: Marked it as an Answer, But still could not get multiple threaded Multiple Notifications Error Fixed. Hoping to see this feature in win10toast or WinAPI as soon as possible...
Thanks For Your Support.